# Drupal twig template doesn't update

Tags: caching, twig, drupal-8

I am facing a weird issue.
I changed my theme "activite" template (node--activite.html.twig). This one is mapped with a js script in another file that I map with the libraries.

Until now, everything worked as well.
But, now, all changes I make don't update the template (even a simple `<div>test</div>`).

What I did :

- clear all caches
- clear cache in Performances menu
- clear cache in database directly

Nothing worked.
There is no server cache and no cache lifetime, no console error.
If I put a console log in a button's template, it's working.

I am on Drupal 8, and I can't change the machine name just for test.

Any advice or solution?

Comment: No one has got an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved.
I don't know why (I am not the only who worked on it), the node path had changed. So each time, I was editing the template from an old path....